# Error accessing content types edit page

Tags: nodes

On a Drupal 6 site, I get a server error whenever I tried to access any of the content types, like:

```
index.php?q=admin/content/node-type/page
```

and I get Internal server error in my browser.

I can see the list of content types:

```
index.php?q=admin/content/types/list
```

But whenever I click on 'Edit' of any of the content types the error occurs.

The site works fine otherwise. I appreciate your hints to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: +1 to 4life's comment, finding the exact error message from your server logs is critical to resolving this. do you know how to access these? you can also enable the "database logging" (dblog) module and check the recent errors reported in your status/reports section but this won't capture everything that your server logs will..